# Loading class different version from third party jar

Tags: java, jar, runtime, classloader

I'm using 2 third party jars (cannot change the class file). Each one uses the same communication jar (same path and name) but of different versions. In case the third party doesn't use the correct version it crashes. for example:

Third Party A.jar calls comm1.3.jar

Third Party B.jar calls comm1.8.jar

Calling to A or B is multithreaded which might take sync issues so i cannot rely on class loader order.

How can i make sure each third party jar will load/use the correct comm jar?

Do you have a code sample?

Thanks in advance,

  Fredy

Comment: In general, you don't. You'd need to shade one of them and skewer the calling bytecode. There are various ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**The same class (identified by a fully qualified name) can only be loaded once per class loader.**

If you need to load 2 different versions of the same library, you can only do that by using module system or by using multiple classloaders.

Comment: Event with two different class loaders, how can I control which class loader the third party jar is using? (Do I need to replace the system classloader before the calls?)

Comment: you'd likely need to convert your system into 2 applications, one that hosts each library separately. I've offered some other approaches to a double class loader solution in my submission

Answer (score 0):

you can mandate a single version of the comms library for both third party jars to collectively use.

sbt:

```
 "org.comms" % "commsjar"                                   % "{mandated comms version}"
 "org.thirdparty.a" % "lib1" % "1.0.0"
exclude("org.comms", "commsjar")
 "org.thirdparty.b" % "lib2" % "1.2.3"
exclude("org.comms", "commsjar")
```

maven:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.comms</groupId>
      <artifactId>commsjar</artifactId>
      <version>{mandated comms version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thirdparty.a</groupId>
      <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.comms</groupId>
          <artifactId>commsjar</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thirdparty.b</groupId>
      <artifactId>lib2</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.comms</groupId>
          <artifactId>commsjar</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

if the mandated jar approach is not viable, then you are going to need take another approach.

You could feasibly run the jars independently of each other in separated applications / class loaders as mentioned by other posters. That probably won't be viable in most systems though as that would be quite an architectural change to the application consuming the libraries.

The best way forward (and the fix to the root cause) would be to find a way to rectify the conflict between the 2 jars my upgrading / downgrading the jars to be compatible enough that there is a comms jar that will work for both libraries. A good tool for doing this is https://mvnrepository.com/. That site lists versions of public libraries and charts their required dependencies (as a range of binary acceptable versions).

You may find that you need to use a combo approach:

- pick library versions of the 2 third party libraries described in mvnrepository.com that are more compatible with each other
- use the exclude pattern described above to mandate the specific version of the comms jar  (this is needed if you don't want to use the default handling of picking the highest version of the 2 dependencies)